# Android findViewById throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, viewflipper

I have a ViewFlipper defined in a separate class.  It looks like this:

```
public class Flipper extends Activity {
    public ViewFlipper view_flipper;

    /* Constructor */
    public Flipper(int flipper_id) {
        view_flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(flipper_id);
    }
    ...
```

Then in another Activity's `onCreate()` method I am instantiating the Flipper like this:

```
private Flipper flipper;
flipper = new Flipper(R.id.login_screen_flipper);
```

However, I get a `NullPointerException` in the constructor of Flipper.  When I debug, I see that `flipper_id` has a valid id.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you instantiate Flipper in another activity, findViewById is called in the constructor of Flipper. It is a method from Flipper class as it extends Activity and surely its call is not valid in the constructor because you do not set content view as it is normally done in Activity.onCreate. Flipper should not extend Activity and you should pass ViewFlipper in a constructor not id.

Comment: Thanks, that saved me!  I ended up instantiating my Flipper like this:
flipper = new Flipper((ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.login_screen_flipper), res);

Answer (score 3):

You can't create Activities like this.

To create an activity you must do it using [Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html). And you have to define the layout in an XML file and attach it using setContentView(R.layout.layout_name);

Have a look at this to start learning: https://developer.android.com/training/index.html

---

UPDATE:

OK, it's unclear of what you are accomplishing with the info of your question.

If you are extending the behaviour of ViewFlipper I suggest you extend it:

```
package your.package;

public class MyFlipper extends ViewFlipper {
    // ...
}
```

Then use it in your xml like this:

```
<your.package.ViewFlipper
    [...] parameters [...] />
```

And finally when you implement it you can do it like this:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    public ViewFlipper viewFlipper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.login_screen_flipper);
    }

    // ... more activity stuff
}
```

PS: It's good custom to use the [lowerCamelCase](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) notation in Java member variables (or fields in Java)

Comment: Suppose that the Flipper class doesn't extend an Activity.  Suppose it is JUST a reusable ViewFlipper class.  Then why would I need intents in that case?